# How to sort .csv file values by combining like strings using python3

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I'm still learning so please bear with me. I've been trying to figure this out for sometime now but have not found what im looking for.

```
My Product.csv file looks like this.

111 ; Info1 ; Description 1 ; Remarks1
123 ; Info1 ; Description 1 ; Remarks1
156 ; Info2 ; Description 2 ; Remarks2
124 ; Info3 ; Description 3 ; Remarks3

I would like to combine entries that are similar like this.

111, 123 ; Info1 ; Description 1 ; Remarks1
156 ; Info2 ; Description 2 ; Remarks2
124 ; Info3 ; Description 3 ; Remarks3

From here i can manipulate my csv file in Excel using vba to insert into a quotation.
```

This is what i would like to achieve using Python. I'm stummped on where to start. I think I need to sart by opening the file and then reading the csv file. After that assign variable to #(i.e. 111) , info, Description, Remarks. Then sort thru the variables and combine like #'s. Then write it back to the file. Please let me know if you need me to calrify anything.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! On to business. What ***exactly*** is your problem? Because, apparently, based on your account, the code solves your issue. What do you need to know or solve at this point? Do you want the code dissected and/or explained? It's also of note that your two blocks of CSV samples are not the same. The first one has `;` delimiters all the way, while the second has both `;` and `,`. Kindly clarify what you want to achieve as a result or state what your exact problem is. This way, we can help you better. :)

Comment: Thanks The Laughing Man, I edited my post and tried to explain what i would like to achieve. Let me know if i can try and make anything more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a task for [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

**EDIT:** I re-factored the first version to improve readability

```
# file group_by_trailing_py2.py
import os
import csv
from itertools import groupby

DELIM=';'
IN_FILENAME = 'My Product.csv'
OUT_FILENAME = 'My Product.grouped.csv'

############  skip this if you run  it against productive data ###############
DATA = '''111 ; Info1 ; Description 1 ; Remarks1
123 ; Info1 ; Description 1 ; Remarks1
156 ; Info2 ; Description 2 ; Remarks2
124 ; Info3 ; Description 3 ; Remarks3'''

if (os.environ.get('WITH_DATA_GENERATION')):
    open(IN_FILENAME,'w').write(DATA)
##############################################################################

keyfunc = lambda row: row[1:]

with open(IN_FILENAME) as csv_file:
    rows = sorted(csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=DELIM), key=keyfunc)

it = map(lambda t: [", ".join(v[0].strip() for v in t[1]) + " "] + t[0],
            groupby(rows, key=keyfunc))

with open(OUT_FILENAME, 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=DELIM)  
    for row in it:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

if run with

```
WITH_DATA_GENERATION=1 python3 group_by_trailing_pk2.py
```

it produces `My Product.grouped.csv` with the content:

```
111, 123 ; Info1 ; Description 1 ; Remarks1
156 ; Info2 ; Description 2 ; Remarks2
124 ; Info3 ; Description 3 ; Remarks3
```

Because you have an existing workload **you will not set WITH_DATA_GENERATION** and delete the code between and including the `'####...'` comment lines.

Comment: Cool that works like a charm. What would be a good starting point to learn more about how you coded that? Also is there a way to save the output back to My Product.csv or does it have to be a different .csv file?

Comment: Looking longer at I'm not so convinced that this should a role model. Let me update that.

Comment: @Geoff ok, that looks more tame now

Comment: Dude you are AMAZING!! Wish i could buy you a beer! Works just like its supposed to Thanks a million!! I've been working on that on and off for little over a year trying to figure it out myself and finally caved this morning to ask for help, THANKS AGAIN SOOO MUCH!

Comment: @Geoff. yw. Cheers! (*you don't forget to accept the answer, don't you*).

Comment: Happy to accept it but still getting used to the site. Also is there something in the code that tells it to write one after another instead of every other row? Is it the check mark to accept?

Comment: Hmm tried defining this as a function but when i run it it doesnt create an out put file :/

Comment: Can't help you without seeing your code. Nevertheless, you can easily, instead of opening the file OUT_FILENAME, write the grouped csv content to sys.stdout  and redirect its output wherever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I re-wrote the solution by decltype_auto to make better re-usable:

```
import csv
import io
from itertools import groupby


def drop_first(row):
    """Returns all but last element."""
    return row[1:]

def make_line(group):
    """Create a text line from a group.

    Joins the grouped result with comma and adds the rest of
    the columns.
    """
    return [", ".join(val[0].strip() for val in group[1]) + " "] + group[0]

def open_path_or_fobj(fobj_or_path, mode='r'):
    """Open a file from a path or return the given file object."""
    if isinstance(fobj_or_path, str):
        return open(fobj_or_path, mode)
    return fobj_or_path

def make_combined(in_fobj_or_path, out_path, delim=';'):
    """Combine lines with same content in first column in one line.
    """
    with open_path_or_fobj(in_fobj_or_path) as csv_file:
        rows = sorted(csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=delim), key=drop_first)

    it = map(make_line, groupby(rows, key=drop_first))

    with open(out_path, 'w') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=delim)  
        for row in it:
            writer.writerow(row)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    def test_with_file():
        """Example for use with existing input file."""

        make_combined('My Product.csv', 'My Product.grouped.csv')

    def test_with_stringio():
        """Test with StringIO object as csv input."""

        data = '''111 ; Info1 ; Description 1 ; Remarks1
        123 ; Info1 ; Description 1 ; Remarks1
        156 ; Info2 ; Description 2 ; Remarks2
        124 ; Info3 ; Description 3 ; Remarks3'''

        fobj_in = io.StringIO(data)
        make_combined(fobj_in, 'result.txt')

        data2 = '''111 # Info1 # Description 1 # Remarks1
        123 # Info1 # Description 1 # Remarks1
        156 # Info2 # Description 2 # Remarks2'''

        fobj_in = io.StringIO(data2)
        make_combined(fobj_in, 'result_delim.txt', delim='#')

    # Actually run it with the file.
    test_with_file()
```

I did a few things:

1. Turn lambda functions into normal function with name and docstring.
2. Use `io.StringIO` to work with sample data defined in the source 
   file as string.
3. Use `if __name__ == '__main__':` to allow import as a module and at
   the same time to use it as a script.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'm not exactly sure how to work with this. I tried running in Idle but it didn't create the My Product.grouped.csv after running it. Im still learning so i probably didn't do something. Also im trying to use this with an Excel ComboButton to launch it. The above answer shows what i tried doing with decltype_auto code. Any help is much appreciated, Thanks Again.

Comment: I added `test_with_file()` in the last line. This will call the function that does the work. Please try again with this additional line..

Comment: Thanks Mike. I tried linking it to my Excel Button and i got this error message. 
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_with_file'


Any Ideas?

Comment: Likely because it is under `if __name__ == '__main__':` and you import your script. Move this function above this if-line (and dedent accordingly). Try again.

Comment: Muller Hey, I tried making this work but i think i don't know what I'm doing. I defined my function like you said and indented the code how i thought it should be. Can you point me in the right directions?